# Yellow tint display on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

After I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 on my laptop tonight, the display is tuned by yellow. It is hard to see things clearly. I have searched the web and also tried adjusting the RGB values from both hardware and software settings, but I ran out of luck. When I boot the laptop into the Windows 10 system on the other partition, the color on display is normal. Can someone please shed some light for how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it's just turned on night light? This setting in  `Settings --> Screen Display --> Night Light`, and try to configure.

Comment: Yup, that's it! The display goes back to normal after turning off the "Night Light". I did not see this option as it was "hidden" in the bottom of the Displays setting. Thank you!

Comment: I have no 'Screen Display' Item in the settings in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.